# Java How to return the size of list using recursive function

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to return the size of a list using a recursive function without using .size().

```
 public static int listSize(ArrayList<Integer> lst){
    if (lst.isEmpty()){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + listSize(lst.remove(0));
}
```

This is what I have tried to do. When running this code I get an error the .remove(0) does not work at all. Why does the .remove(0) not work within this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst.remove(0)
```

removes the zero-th element of the list, but it doesn't return a list, it returns the element it removed.

So you instead need to do something like

```
lst.remove(0);
return 1 + listSize(lst);
```

One very important thing to keep in mind - you are "destroying" the list being handed to that method.  That is not what one would expect when calling a method named `listSize()` - you would expect two calls to that method (with no intervening changes to the list) to return the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You're just doing it incorrectly.  List.remove() doesn't return a list.

```java
      List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
      System.out.println(listSize(a));


   public static int listSize(List<Integer> lst) {
      if (lst.isEmpty()) {
         return 0;
      }
      lst.remove(0);
      return 1 + listSize(lst);
   }
```

And here is a version that restores the list by putting the elements back in the correct order.

```java
   public static int listSize(List<Integer> lst) {
      int b;
      if (lst.isEmpty()) {
         return 0;
      }
      b = lst.remove(0);
      int v = 1 + listSize(lst);
      lst.add(0, b);
      return v;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
 public static int listSize(ArrayList<Integer> lst){
    if (lst.isEmpty()){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + listSize(lst.subList(1, lst.size()));
}
```

Comment: The OP specifically said they didn't want to use List.size().

Answer (score 0):

To avoid sideEffects one may clone the list while performing the operations

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList();
        integerList.add(1);
        integerList.add(1);
        integerList.add(1);
        integerList.add(1);
        integerList.add(1);
        integerList.add(1);
        System.out.println("Length:: " + findListSizeByRecursion(integerList));

    }

    public static int findListSizeByRecursion(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList){
        List<Integer> clonedArrayList = (List<Integer>) arrayList.clone();
        if (clonedArrayList.isEmpty()){
            return 0;
        }
        clonedArrayList.remove(0);
        return 1 + findListSizeByRecursion((ArrayList<Integer>) clonedArrayList);
    }
}
```